# Cloud SQL Stuck with "Operation is in progress"

Tags: sql, mysql, maintenance-mode

We have been locked out of our MySQL instance for a few, and it does not respond to any commands. Either in MySQL CLI, Gcloud CLI locally and Gcloud shell nor restart, start, stop or edit. Have any of you experienced this, and know a workaround?

Either in MySQL CLI, Gcloud CLI locally and Gcloud shell nor restart, start, stop or edit. Have any of you experienced this, and know a workaround?